# How to calculate the depth of the custom object with subObjects of the same type?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tree

I have an object call CEKnot and it has property called subknots which is an array of similar CEKnot objects. Now I want to calculate how deep this tree goes.. This is not a binary tree as the subknots can be more than two. here is the code I have tried..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CEProjectDTO* project = [self.tblViewDatasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CEServiceSession *serviceSession = [CEServiceSession new];

    [CEProgressHUD showWithTitle:@"Loading..."];

    [serviceSession.projectPhaseService getProjectPhasesWithProjectID:project.i3D onFinish:^(NSArray * phaseList){
        self.phaseDTOList = phaseList;
        NSLog(@"Count is %d",[self.phaseDTOList count]);
        [CEProgressHUD hide];
    }onError:^(NSString *title, NSString *message) {
        [CEProgressHUD hide];
        [CEAlertViewHelper showOKAlertViewWithTitle:title message:message];
    }];
    self.mindMapLevelObjectCount = nil;
    self.mindMapLevelObjectCount = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.level  = 1;

    self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel = 0;

    CEProjectToKnotConverter* converter = [CEProjectToKnotConverter new];
    CEProjectKnot* baseKnot = [converter convertProject:project withPhases:self.phaseDTOList];

    self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel = self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel + [baseKnot.subKnots count];
    [self.mindMapLevelObjectCount setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.level]];
    self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel = 0;

    self.level  = 2;


    [self calculateMindMapLevels:baseKnot];

    NSLog(@"MIND MAP LEVEL OBJE %@", self.mindMapLevelObjectCount);


    CEMindMapViewController *mindMapViewController = [[CEViewControllerManager sharedInstance] createViewController:[CEMindMapViewController class]];
    mindMapViewController.baseKnot = baseKnot;
    [self presentModalViewController:mindMapViewController animated:YES];


}
-(void)calculateMindMapLevels:(CEKnot*)projectKnot{


    for (CEKnot* subKnot in projectKnot.subKnots) {
        self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel = self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel + [subKnot.subKnots count];
        NSLog(@"Level %d total of nots %d  project not subknot %d", self.level,self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel, [subKnot.subKnots count]);
    }
        [self.mindMapLevelObjectCount setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.level]];


    for (CEKnot* subKnot in projectKnot.subKnots) {
        [self calculateMindMapLevels:subKnot];
        self.numberOfKnotsOnThisLevel = 0;
    }
    self.level = _level +1;

}
```

I am not getting the depth correctly and have tried numerous algorithm but cant get the depth correct. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Long as your tree does not store its depth you have to get the Level of each knot and return the highest.

A recursive -untested- approach

```
int numberOfLevels(CEKnot *knot, int parentLevel) {
  int ownLevel = parentLevel+1;
  int highestLevel = ownLevel;
  for (CEKnot* subKnot in knot) {
    int subLevel = numberOfLevels(subKnot, ownLevel);
    highestLevel = MAX(highestLevel, subLevel);
  }
  return highestLevel;
}
```